# React: Error on props update from parent (Failed to execute removeChild)

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using react and ajax to fetch data for a list. After first init I always get the following error when `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` is executed. This happens when the URL for the ajax changed.

Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Here is the code:

```
class QuickList extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // set initial data to empty array
    this.state = { 
      data: [] 
    }

  }

  _loadQuickListDataFromServer(url){
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: (data) => {
        this.setState({data: data});
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }
    });
  }


  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('url: ', nextProps.url);
    this._loadQuickListDataFromServer(nextProps.url);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('url: ', this.props.url);
    // if component is mounted then fetch data from server
    this._loadQuickListDataFromServer(this.props.url);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container-fluid text-center'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-sm-12'>
            <CustomDataTable data={this.state.data} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// defined in return of other react component
<QuickList url={quickListURL} />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you still get the error if you remove the `<CustomDataTable/>` component? I'm wondering if it could be something in there and not your Quicklist component. If you make the component have a key that will change with the new data, it would force that component to unmount and remount.

Comment: you are right. If I remove <CustomDataTable/> then I don't get the error. But how to solve passing the new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issue is with the `CustomDataTable`, you can try to parse in there further to debug the issue, but without seeing the code, the only thing I could recommend is to force an unmount of that component when the URL changes.

```
<CustomDataTable key={this.props.url} data={this.state.data} />
```

This should cause the component to remount whenever the key changes.

Comment: yes, that's it. Could have been found here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children

Comment: Amazing! good thinking with the mount unmount! i guess react wants us to know a whole bunch of moving parts to have a smooth ui